# A statement in an If clause never gets executed

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The last statement in my If statement `Cells(cont, 3).Value = esp2 & CANTIDAD` never gets executed.

```vb
CANTIDAD = Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(cont, 2)

If CANTIDAD > 9 Then
 Cells(cont, 3).Value = esp & CANTIDAD

ElseIf CANTIDAD <= 9 ThenCells(cont, 3).Value = esp1 & CANTIDAD

ElseIf CANTIDAD > 99 Then

Cells(cont, 3).Value = esp2 & CANTIDAD
```

Comment: Walk through the logic in your head, line by line, when the value of `CANTIDAD` is 200. What do you _expect_ to happen in that scenario? Also, you have some really obvious syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

### If Statement Cases

- Note the importance of the order of the cases: if you check *greater than 9* before *greater than 99*, then *greater than 99* will never be checked.

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Hoja1")
    
    Dim cont As Long, Cantidad As Double
    
    ' For cont = ...
    
        Cantidad = ws.Cells(cont, "B").Value
        
        If Cantidad <= 9 Then ' 1.
            ws.Cells(cont, "C").Value = esp1 & Cantidad
        ElseIf Cantidad > 99 Then ' 2.
            ws.Cells(cont, "C").Value = esp2 & Cantidad
        ElseIf Cantidad > 9 Then ' 3.
            ws.Cells(cont, "C").Value = esp & Cantidad
        End If
        
        ' Or more elegantly:
'        Select Case Cantidad
'            Case Is <= 9: ws.Cells(cont, "C").Value = esp1 & Cantidad
'            Case Is > 99: ws.Cells(cont, "C").Value = esp2 & Cantidad
'            Case Is > 9: ws.Cells(cont, "C").Value = esp & Cantidad
'        End Select
    
    
    'Next cont
    
End Sub
```

**All Cases Ordered Ascending**

```
<= 9
> 9 <= 99
> 99
```

- If you want to use them in this order then the second one has to have two conditions:

  ```
  ElseIf Cantidad > 9 And Cantidad <= 99 Then
  ```

Comment: `ElseIf Cantidad > 9 Then ' 3.` At that point the result is always True so `Else` would suffice.

Comment: @CDP1802 Thanks for the input. You are right, but I'm leaving it like that for the sake of better understanding (readability). Not sure if you've noticed how it is much better (more readable) to use first the greatest (`>99`), then the middle (`>9`), and then the `Else`. One could say something like, If you can't keep it in ascending order because you're too lazy to use two conditions, then at least use a descending order if you're going to 'Else' the last statement.

Comment: Yes. I dont think _then the second one has to have two conditions_  is true because Cantidad is >9 for the first condition <= 9 to fail. So it reduced to `Case Is <= 9 : Case Is <= 99: Case Else`. It means the 9 only has to be changed in one place

Comment: Guess I need to get my head examined. Thx.